# What is the best/most efficient way to measure time when running a program in C?

Tags: c, performance

How can i record the running time of my program every time I insert an input?I tried this particular method:

```
clock_t tStart = clock(),tEnd;
```

And after printing the ouput:

```
tEnd = clock();
printf("Time taken: %.6fs\n", (double)(tEnd - tStart) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

However,I sometimes end up having just a bunch of 0s when calculating the miliseconds.Is there any method to improve this?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any method to improve this?

If you don't have a better timer, as suggested in jspcal's answer, then another solution is to repeat the same operation a large number of times and then divide the elapsed time by the number of repetitions:

```
const int REPS = 10000;
clock_t tStart = clock(),tEnd;
for (int i = 0; i < REPS; i++) {
    // do your work here
}
tEnd = clock();
double time = (double)(tEnd - tStart)/REPS;
printf("Time taken: %.6fs\n", time / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

Comment: I tried your solution,but I realized that it doesn't work quite how I expected.For sure,it does record the running time of my program more accurately,however I don't know how to exactly implement this such that a single data input is generated randomly and then printing the output one single time for that particular input.

Comment: @Neri-kun If the point is to measure the time needed for your calculation, then you can repeat the calculation with the same input and leave the output until after the loop — you're probably not interested in how long `printf` takes, and including it will only distort the measurement of the calculation. If you really want to measure an average run time with different inputs, then generate random inputs and put them in an array before the loop, and then read them from the array with `i` as the index.

Comment: You can obviously get as fancy as you like when you're measuring your code, but that's getting into a different question than what you seem to have asked about. The point of running the same code in a loop with the same input is just to multiply the execution time so that you can minimize the effect of inaccuracy due to your clock, system interrupts, etc.

Comment: I also forgot to ask you one more thing regarding your solution.Why did you choose a constant integer of 10000?Does it represent a certain number of milliseconds or seconds?

Comment: No particular reason for that number -- it's just big round number, and it's easy to do the math in your head. But if you like 9,731 better, use that. Or if you decide that 1,000 reps sufficiently minimizes the error in your measurement, that's fine too.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps try a higher resolution timer which may be available on your platform:

```
Linux: clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &timeSpec)
Windows: QueryPerformanceCounter(&performanceCount)
```

Comment: But how do i actually implement this?For the record I use Windows and Visual Studio 2017 as IDE.

Comment: Perhaps try this example on Windows https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/815668/how-to-use-the-queryperformancecounter-function-to-time-code-in-visual

Answer (score 1):

In unix,use`time` , which forks&execs the program, and does a `get_rusage()` after the child exited.

So, you don't have to instrument the program itself.

---

```
plasser@pisbak:$ time ./a.out omg.dat 

real    0m10.276s
user    0m9.986s
sys 0m0.291s
plasser@pisbak:$
```

Comment: Sounds interesting,however I don't have UNIX as OS on my laptop.